# Basic Authentication Middleware with OWIN and ASP.NET WEB API

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, wif, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I created an ASP.NET WEB API 2.2 project. I used the Windows Identity Foundation based template for individual accounts available in visual studio [see it here](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/creating-web-projects-in-visual-studio).

The web client (written in angularJS) uses OAUTH implementation with web browser cookies to store the token and the refresh token. We benefit from the helpful *UserManager* and *RoleManager* classes for managing users and their roles.
Everything works fine with OAUTH and the web browser client.

However, for some retro-compatibility concerns with desktop based clients I also need to support Basic authentication. Ideally, I would like the *[Authorize]*, *[Authorize(Role = "administrators")]* etc. attributes to work with both OAUTH and Basic authentication scheme.

Thus, following the code from [LeastPrivilege](https://github.com/IdentityModel/Owin.BasicAuthentication/tree/master/source/IdentityModel.Owin.BasicAuthentication) I created an OWIN *BasicAuthenticationMiddleware* that inherits from *AuthenticationMiddleware*.
 I came to the following implementation. For the *BasicAuthenticationMiddleWare* only the Handler has changed compared to the Leastprivilege's code. Actually we use ClaimsIdentity rather than a series of *Claim*.

```cs
 class BasicAuthenticationHandler: AuthenticationHandler<BasicAuthenticationOptions>
{
    private readonly string _challenge;

    public BasicAuthenticationHandler(BasicAuthenticationOptions options)
    {
        _challenge = "Basic realm=" + options.Realm;
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticationTicket> AuthenticateCoreAsync()
    {
        var authzValue = Request.Headers.Get("Authorization");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authzValue) || !authzValue.StartsWith("Basic ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var token = authzValue.Substring("Basic ".Length).Trim();
        var claimsIdentity = await TryGetPrincipalFromBasicCredentials(token, Options.CredentialValidationFunction);

        if (claimsIdentity == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            Request.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
            return new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity, new AuthenticationProperties());
        }
    }

    protected override Task ApplyResponseChallengeAsync()
    {
        if (Response.StatusCode == 401)
        {
            var challenge = Helper.LookupChallenge(Options.AuthenticationType, Options.AuthenticationMode);
            if (challenge != null)
            {
                Response.Headers.AppendValues("WWW-Authenticate", _challenge);
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    async Task<ClaimsIdentity> TryGetPrincipalFromBasicCredentials(string credentials,
        BasicAuthenticationMiddleware.CredentialValidationFunction validate)
    {
        string pair;
        try
        {
            pair = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                Convert.FromBase64String(credentials));
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            return null;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var ix = pair.IndexOf(':');
        if (ix == -1)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var username = pair.Substring(0, ix);
        var pw = pair.Substring(ix + 1);

        return await validate(username, pw);
    }
```

Then in Startup.Auth I declare the following delegate for validating authentication (simply checks if the user exists and if the password is right and generates the associated *ClaimsIdentity*)

```cs
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(DbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

        Func<string, string, Task<ClaimsIdentity>> validationCallback = (string userName, string password) =>
        {
            using (DbContext dbContext = new DbContext())
            using(UserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(dbContext))
            using(ApplicationUserManager userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(userStore))
            {
                var user = userManager.FindByName(userName);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                bool ok = userManager.CheckPassword(user, password);
                if (!ok)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                return Task.FromResult(claimsIdentity);
            }
        };

        var basicAuthOptions = new BasicAuthenticationOptions("KMailWebManager", new BasicAuthenticationMiddleware.CredentialValidationFunction(validationCallback));
        app.UseBasicAuthentication(basicAuthOptions);
        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            //If the AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan is changed, also change the ExpiresUtc in the RefreshTokenProvider.cs.
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            RefreshTokenProvider = new RefreshTokenProvider()
        };

        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    }
```

However, even with settings the *Request.User* in Handler's *AuthenticationAsyncCore* method the *[Authorize]* attribute does not work as expected: responding with error 401 unauthorized every time I try to use the Basic Authentication scheme.
Any idea on what is going wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found out the culprit, in the WebApiConfig.cs file the 'individual user' template inserted the following lines.

```
//// Web API configuration and services
//// Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

Thus we also have to register our *BasicAuthenticationMiddleware*

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(BasicAuthenticationOptions.BasicAuthenticationType));
```

where BasicAuthenticationType is the constant string "Basic" that is passed to the base constructor of *BasicAuthenticationOptions*

```
public class BasicAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationOptions
{
    public const string BasicAuthenticationType = "Basic";

    public BasicAuthenticationMiddleware.CredentialValidationFunction CredentialValidationFunction { get; private set; }

    public BasicAuthenticationOptions( BasicAuthenticationMiddleware.CredentialValidationFunction validationFunction)
        : base(BasicAuthenticationType)
    {
        CredentialValidationFunction = validationFunction;
    }
}
```